# Ubuntu 13.10 and catkin

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try anything at all with catkin, the system is unable to find it, unable to download it, unable to install it, anything at all. I need it in order to do a custom build gazebo-ros-pkgs, and I am unable to do anything with catkin because it cannot be found.

```
   dev@dev-700Z7C:~$ catkin_
    catkin_create_pkg          catkin_tag_changelog
    catkin_find_pkg            catkin_test_changelog
    catkin_generate_changelog  
    dev@dev-700Z7C:~$ cd Code/
    dev@dev-700Z7C:~/Code$ cd catkin/
    dev@dev-700Z7C:~/Code/catkin$ cd src
    dev@dev-700Z7C:~/Code/catkin/src$ catkin_init_workspace
    catkin_init_workspace: command not found
    dev@dev-700Z7C:~/Code/catkin/src$ ^C
    dev@dev-700Z7C:~/Code/catkin/src$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/99116/ubuntu-13.10-and-catkin/) by [quantumrobotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/8591/quantumrobotics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are trying to run the catkin commands in a shell without the ROS directories added to the PATH. Specifically, you need to run either manually or in your .bashrc: `source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash`

Take a closer look at the setup tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment

---

Originally posted by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) with karma: 971 on 2013-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0